# I have changed the path trajectory in VS code application and now whatever I do in terminal it shows- zsh: command not found. what to do in this

Tags: python, visual-studio, terminal, path, zsh

terminal
pip install pandas
Run ->
zsh : command not found : pip

it happens with every other thing I run in terminal. so what to do in this situation?

I tried to change path trajectory to - $PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin. but still its showing same problem.

and then I did factory reset to my macbook and then installed vs code and tried running the same in the terminal but still ended up with same problem.

Comment: You don't show in your posting your PATH. Since you are using zsh, post a screenshot where you do on the command line a `echo $path;  pip install pandas Run`.

Comment: _it happens with every other thing _ : Do you mean that even if you do a, say, `pwd`, you get the message _command not found : **pip**_? I would like to see a screenshot from this as well.